# How would I wrap a texture around a cylinder without it looking off?

Tags: modeling, texturing

Im making a chrome exhaust muffler for a racing game but when I try to texture it, i get this ugly line going down the center and when I look at the uv map it seems that one side of the texture is jumping to the other side of the surface, if that makes sense so it looks very off. How would I fix this?
[image: Sides Jumping]

[image: inside of it]

[image: That "Ugly line"]

Answer (score 2):

This is because your texture is not "seamless" mainly due to the reflective shine in the middle:
[image]

You need a seamless texture and then bake the shine on it if you need it on the texture.
Something like these: https://naldzgraphics.net/free-seamless-metal-textures/
But since you said it was for a game, you'd have to make sure the textures are allowed for use in games and not *just* personal use.

Alternatively, you could look into "Procedurally Generated Textures" there are lots of tutorials on it. This is a great way to generate seamless textures without the worry of copyright.